# google apps script + api vk messages.send Post запрос

Tags: vkontakte-api, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь настроить регулярную рассылку из Гугл таблиц по списку контактов от специально созданной для этой цели группы.
Все подготовительные действия сделаны. 
С помощью GET-запроса все прекрасно работает.

```
function vkSendMsg(id, msg) {
  var token = VALID_MSG_TOKEN;
  var user_id = id;
  var message = msg;
  var apiMsg =  "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiMsg+"?"+"user_id="+user_id+"&"+"message="+message+"&"+"access_token="+token);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
} //Все ок
```

Но хочу сделать с помощью POST-запороса

```
  function vkSendMsgPost(id, msg) {
  var token = VALID_MSG_TOKEN;
  var user_id = id;
  var message = msg;
  var apiMsg =  "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send";

  var data = {
   'user_id': user_id,
   'message': message,
   'access_token': token
 };
 var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
 };
  var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiMsg, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}//Возвращает ошибку авторизации (№5)
```

Ошибка:
{"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: no access_token passed.","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"messages.send"}]}}

Что я делаю не так? И что нужно сделать чтобы сообщения все-таки отправлялись?

Comment: Вопрос не в тему, как вы проходите oAuth flow? Дело в том, что я поддерживаю одну библиотеку на GS, но никак не могу подобрать оптимальный вариант редиректа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы отправляете в своем примере данные как JSON payload, поэтому ВК не может прочитать их. Надо отправлять обычный POST-запрос:

```
function vkSendMsgPost(id, msg) {
  var token = VALID_MSG_TOKEN;
  var user_id = id;
  var message = msg;
  var apiMsg = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';

  var data = {
    'user_id': user_id,
    'message': message,
    'access_token': token
  };

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data
  };

  var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiMsg, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Я заменил `JSON.stringify(data)` на `data` и убрал `'contentType': 'application/json'`.